# PHP - Check if dir exists with starting mask

Tags: php, rmdir

I want to check with php if a dir in my directory exist with a starting mask TEMP

My temp directories looks like this:

TEMP20130222001408378716  etc.

```
$dir="mydirecrtory/*";
$dirmask="TEMP";

foreach(glob($dir/TEMP*) AS tempdir)

    if (!is_dir($dir/$tempdir) || !$dir = opendir($dir/$tempdir)) {

rmdir($dir/$tempdir);
}
```

Comment: Great. And what is the question?

Comment: Will it work and is there somebody who has a better idea?

Comment: Have you tested it? Did it work?

Comment: First test then if you have issue then say

Comment: Are you not facing the problem with this code as it has the error.